# About Enlightened badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I just noticed the description of the "Enlightened" badge *seems* contradictory.

**Enlightened: First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes. This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

If it's awarded for the first answer from the user with at least 10 up votes, then it cannot be awarded multiple times. Am I missing something here? Or does "first" here mean that it was the first answer to a particular question and ended up getting 10 up votes and accepted.

Edit: This link has detailed descriptions of all the badges.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397#67399

Comment: This thread on meta.SO clarifies it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/badge-descriptions-ambiguous

Comment: @Nuno: Thanks. Some of them indeed seem ambiguous.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that it was the first answer to a particular question and ended up getting 10 up votes and being accepted.  So at most one enlightened badge can be awarded per question, but the same user can earn multiple enlightened badges for multiple questions.

From personal experience, I know that if an answer had previously been posted but was deleted, then the enlightened badge can still be awarded.  I guess the code just checks for an accepted answer with a net vote count of at least 10 and the earliest time stamp of all undeleted answers to the question.

For examples, you click on the enlightened badge on a user's page to see for which questions they were awarded.

Comment: Interestingly, you ended up getting the Enlightened badge for this answer.

Comment: @Tim: Who'd have thought it? ;)

Comment: @J.M.:Probably the person who cast the 10th vote :)

Comment: Thanks to the voters for helping to provide an additional example.